# Foreach to calculate multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I'm stuck on a problem I'm trying to sort out with calculating multiple arrays.

Here's the scenario...

A user will input their card number i.e. 1234, and then I need it multiple each number stored in another array in a sequence of 1,2,1,2.

So it would calculate in according 1 * 1, 2 * 2, 3 * 1, 4 * 2, etc.

I've tried a few different to calculate both inside a single foreach loop, however I'm having no such luck as I'm returning duplicates, so I'm seeing if there's even a way I can combine both arrays into a single foreach loop?

I'm able to print the data, so now I'm just seeing how I can multiple them together. Here's what I have so far...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter your Card Number");
       char[] card = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
       int[] card_m = { 1,2,1,2 };

       foreach (char c in card)
       {
           int number = (int)char.GetNumericValue(c);
           Console.WriteLine("Converted Number: {0}", number);
       }

       foreach (int m in card_m)
           Console.WriteLine("Card Number Multiplier: {0}", m);

       Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `card_m.Length == card.Length`?

Comment: How about using a `for` loop? That way you can use the counter of the for loop as the index for accessing both the arrays.

Comment: Does all card numbers consist of four digits?

Comment: Thanks, yeah for this example I'm only using 4 characters, so the card_m and card lengths will be identical. I figured the foreach would be more ideal (guess not), so I'll try it out with the for loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the arrays may be different lengths, use the modulus operator to loop on your multiplier array:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Card Number");

        char[] card = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();

        int[] card_m = { 1, 2 };

        for (int idx = 0; idx < card.Length; idx++) {
            int number = (int) char.GetNumericValue(card[idx]);
            Console.WriteLine("Converted Number: {0}", number);

            // pull the multiplier from the card_m array
            int m = card_m[idx % card_m.Length];

            Console.WriteLine("Card Number Multiplier: {0}", m);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Indeed. I just wanted to wrap my head around this particular item first. This is precisely what I'm looking "for". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help...  Be sure to add any appropriate error checking along the way.  For example, `GetNumericValue()` will return -1 if the string was not a number.

Answer (score 2):

For any length card number, you can just use `Aggregate()` to calculate the value for each digit, and sum them up.

```
int coefficient = 2;
chksum =  input.Aggregate(0, (sum, ch) => sum + (ch - '0') * (coefficient ^= 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example,

```
var multiplied = card.Select(char.GetNumericValue).Zip(card_m, (a,b) => a*b);
```

This won't be valid if `card_m.Length != card.Length` because it'll only "zip" until the end of the shortest list.

[MSDN Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) -- *Merges two sequences by using the specified predicate function.*

You can add the extension method below and run this code to repeat `card_m`:

```
var multiplied = card.Select(char.GetNumericValue)
                     .Zip(card_m.Indefinite(), (a,b) => a*b);

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Indefinite(this int[] source)
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (true)
            yield return source[i++ % source.Length];
    }
}
```

Comment: `Zip` is a function that takes two lists `[a, b, c]` and `[x, y, z]` and combines them into one list `[(a, x), (b, y), (c, z)]`. The C# version, rather than grouping them into tuples, takes a function that describes how to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are doing
do your card and card_m always are of same length?

if so you could do something like ( you have to make sure first)

```
for(int i =0;i<card.Length;i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", ((int)char.GetNumericValue(card[i]))*card_m[i]);
}
```

Comment: You can just loop up to Math.Min(card.Length, card_m.Length) to handle the case where they're not the same, if there is a need for it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate two arrays in a single `foreach` loop. You have to use a plain old `for` loop in that case. [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loop_over_multiple_arrays_simultaneously#C.23) has an example.

Comment: Sure you can, it's just less convenient.  The trivial method: just define your own counter and increment it at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
card.Select(char.GetNumericValue).Zip(card_m, (c, n) => c*n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
for (int i = 0; i < card.Length; i++)
{
  var result = (int)char.GetNumericValue( card[i]) * (int)char.GetNumericValue(m_card[i]);
}
```

Comment: Missing the conversion from char to int, but otherwise fine.

Comment: Now you're converting both from chars to ints; only one of the two is a char array.  The other is already an int array.  If you're not done then you shouldn't post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with this assuming you might have more than 4 digits in your card number

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Card Number");
            char[] card = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
            int[] card_m = { 1, 2, 1, 2 };
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (char c in card)
            {
                int value = (int)char.GetNumericValue(c) * card_m[counter++%card_m.Length];
                Console.WriteLine("Converted Number: {0}", value);
            }
```